# Sorting a CSV file by district

Tags: java, csv, sorting

Hello I wanna create a program that sorts the following csv file I'm trying to sort the file by their district. So the following program reads the file and is able to sort it but it sorts it by their name and I wanna change it so it sorts by district any help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortDistrict
{
    private static final String COLUMN_SEPARATOR = ",";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("data.csv");
        List<List<String>> lines = readCsv(inputStream);

        // Create a comparator that compares the elements from column 0,
        // in ascending order
        Comparator<List<String>> c0 = createAscendingComparator(0);

        // Create a comparator that compares the elements from column 2,
        // in descending order
        Comparator<List<String>> c1 = createDesendingComparator(2);

        // Create a comparator that compares primarily by using c0,
        // and secondarily by using c1
        Comparator<List<String>> comparator = createComparator(c0, c1);
        Collections.sort(lines, comparator);

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.csv");
        String header = "Last Name, First Name, Email, Address, Age, District, Gender";
        writeCsv(header, lines, outputStream);
    }

    private static List<List<String>> readCsv(
            InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String line = null;

        // Skip header
        line = reader.readLine();

        while (true)
        {
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(line.split(COLUMN_SEPARATOR));
            lines.add(list);
        }
        return lines;
    }

    private static void writeCsv(
            String header, List<List<String>> lines, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException
    {
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        writer.write(header+"\n");
        for (List<String> list : lines)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                writer.write(list.get(i));
                if (i < list.size() - 1)
                {
                    writer.write(COLUMN_SEPARATOR);
                }
            }
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        writer.close();

    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private static <T> Comparator<T>
    createComparator(Comparator<? super T>... districts)
    {
        return (t0, t1) ->
        {
            for (Comparator<? super T> district : districts)
            {
                int n = district.compare(t0, t1);
                if (n != 0)
                {
                    return n;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        };
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<List<T>>
    createAscendingComparator(int index)
    {
        return createListAtIndexComparator(Comparator.naturalOrder(), index);
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<List<T>>
    createDesendingComparator(int index)
    {
        return createListAtIndexComparator(Comparator.reverseOrder(), index);
    }

    private static <T> Comparator<List<T>>
    createListAtIndexComparator(Comparator<? super T> delegate, int index)
    {
        return (list0, list1) ->
                delegate.compare(list0.get(index), list1.get(index));
    }
}
```

I also have a Person class if it'll be any use

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String residency;
    private String gender;
    private int age;
    private int district;


    public Person(String name, String email, String address, String gender, String residency, int district, int age) {

        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
        this.district = district;
        this.residency = residency;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getResidency() {
        return residency;
    }

    public int getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (name + "," + email + "," + address + "," + age + "," + residency + "," + district + "," + gender);
    }
    public int compareTo(Person another) {
        if (district == another.getDistrict())
            return 0;
        else if (district < another.getDistrict())
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    } // end of compareTo
} // end of Person
```

The csv file is quite big but here is a few lines
First Name, Last Name, Email, Address, Age, Residency, District, Gender

```
Colleen,Joyner,commodo.auctor@elementumat.net,Ap #697-1279 Nullam Road,30,Resident,4,Female
Fay,Parker,augue.ut.lacus@egetvarius.edu,"P.O. Box 234, 6576 Et, Ave",24,Resident,4,Female
TaShya,Atkinson,sem.egestas@urna.com,"6319 At, St.",45,Resident,15,Female
Curran,Shannon,massa@arcu.com,"980 In, Rd.",57,Resident,8,Male
Yolanda,Snyder,ipsum.ac@Sednullaante.org,"P.O. Box 769, 8207 Egestas Avenue",54,Non-Resident,4,Female
Candice,Weaver,ligula@Aenean.ca,"Ap #599-9287 Tellus, Rd.",35,Resident,9,Female
Yoshio,Silva,fames@Cumsociisnatoque.co.uk,Ap #327-6404 Dui St.,19,Resident,4,Male
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the CSV files are quite large then use a temporary database (like SQLite) to do the sorting. Write the sorted records into a new CSV file. If you would like a demo of this then E-Mail me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort a large CSV file by a specific field and output result to another CSV file. The code will be complex and lengthy if you try to do this in Java.
Yet, with SPL, the open-source Java package, you only need one line of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | >file("output.csv").export@ct(file("data.csv").cursor@cqt().sortx(District)) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as sort.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st=con.prepareCall("call sortx()");
st.execute();
…
```

Or execute the SPL string within a Java program as we execute a SQL statement:

```
…
st = con.prepareStatement("=>file(\"output.csv\").export@ct(file(\"data.csv\").cursor@cqt().sortx(District))");
st.execute();
…
```